# Fastest way to detect and append duplicates base on specific column in dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, fuzzy-search, fuzzywuzzy

Here are samples data:

```
name         age       gender     school
Michael Z    21        Male       Lasalle
Lisa M       22        Female     Ateneo
James T      21        Male       UP
Michael Z.   23        Male       TUP
```

Here are the expected output I need:

```
name       age     gender     similar name  on_lasalle on_ateneo on_up on_tup
Michael Z  21      Male       Michael Z.    True       False     False True
Lisa M     22      Female                   False      True      False False
James T    21      Male                     False      False     True  False
```

I've been trying to use `fuzzywuzzy` on my python script. The data I am getting is coming from `bigquery`, then I am comverting it to `dataframe` to clean some stuff. After that, I am converting the `dataframe` to a `list of dictionaries`.

Notice the above data where Michael Z. from TUP was appended to Michael Z from school Lasalle since they have similar names with 100% similarity rate using `fuzz.token_set_ratio`

What I want is to get all similar rows base on names and append it to the current dictionary we are looking at (including their school).

Here is the code and the loop to get similar rows base on names:

```
data_dict_list = data_df.to_dict('records')

for x in range(0, len(data_dict_list)):
    for y in range(x, len(data_dict_list)):
         if not data_dict_list[x]['is_duplicate']:
              similarity = fuzz.token_set_ratiod(data_dict_list[x]['name'], data_dict_list[y]['name'])
                   if similarity >= 90:
                       data_dict_list[x]['similar_names'].update('similar_name': data_dict_list[y]['name'])
                       ...
                       data_dict_list[x]['is_duplicate'] = True
```

The runtime of this script is very slow, as sometimes, I am getting 100,000+ data !!! So it will loop through all of that data.

How will I be able to speed up the process of this?

Suggesting `pandas` is much appreciated as I am having a hard time figuring out how to loop data in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a first step you can simply replace the import of `fuzzywuzzy` with [`rapidfuzz`](https://github.com/maxbachmann/RapidFuzz):

```py
from rapidfuzz import fuzz
```

which should already improve the performance quite a bit. You can further improve the performance by comparing complete lists of strings in rapidfuzz in the following way:

```py
>> import pandas as pd
>> from rapidfuzz import process, fuzz
>> df = pd.DataFrame(data={'name': ['test', 'tests']})
>> process.cdist(df['name'], df['name'], scorer=fuzz.token_set_ratio, score_cutoff=90)
array([[100,   0],
       [  0, 100]], dtype=uint8)
```

which returns a matrix of result where all elements with a score below 90 are set to 0. For large datasets you can enable multithreading using the `workers` argument:

```py
process.cdist(df['name'], df['name'], workers=-1, scorer=fuzz.token_set_ratio, score_cutoff=90)
```

Comment: Good suggestion. I will try this out.

Comment: With using score_cuttoff, it will only show the score with greater than that value. In such case how will you identify which score came for which value?

Comment: `process.cdist` always returns the full result matrix. So when using `score_cutoff`, those values will still be part of the matrix, but will be set to a score worse than `score_cutoff`. So e.g. for `fuzz.token_set_ratio` they will be set to 0. In contrast `process.extract`, `process.extractOne` and `process.extract_iter` will filter them out, but return the index of the corresponding values.